# How can an ethereum node read a contract call arguments?

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging

I'm playing around with ethereum and I know that any data sent to a node must be processed by all nodes in the network.

When I look into my `geth` terminal I don't see any of that data. Is there a way to view this? Specifically I was wondering about looking at the values passed to a public function when it is called

Comment: Not any data sent to a node (a peer) has to be processed by all nodes in the network). The data which has to be processed by all nodes in every case are blocks of the blockchain. They contain transactions most times, which contain the transfer of value, data or smart contract function calls. The smart contract function calls can on the other hand transfer value or create and modify storage data. The verification of every block is crucial, because every node has to accept that the block is not corrupt. If some nodes don't agree but others do, the network gets seperated (fork).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A contract call actually is a transaction execution with extra data containing smart contract function and input value for each that function's arguments. That's why everyone can read/see the contract call arguments.

Comment: Is there a way for me to know the transaction id? Note there is an event in the function, if I look for the event can I get the transaction id?

Comment: the events was recorded in the tnx's receipts/logs but base on the events, we cannot get exactly what is the tnx id.